# Flutter・dioを用いてデータを取得したい

Tags: flutter

dioを用いてデータを取得したいと考えています。
dioのアドレス指定したページのデータは取れますが、表示に用いる下層のデータの取得ができないか試行錯誤しています。

dioに https://www.dhl.com/jp-ja/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=xxxxxxxxxx （GET/UTF-8）を渡すと、https://www.dhl.com/jp-ja/home/tracking/tracking-express.html は取得できますが、
XMLHttpRequest(XHR)が取得したいのです。

[image: 階層図]

どのようにしたら取得できるでしょうか？
ヒントになることや、参考になるものなどどんなことでもいいのでアドバイスいただければ幸いです。

```
  var dio = Dio();
  Response response = await dio.get('https://www.dhl.com/jp-ja/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=xxxxxxxxxx');
  print(response.data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解析の結果、下記のアドレスをdioに渡すことで、解決しました。
https://www.dhl.com/utapi?trackingNumber=xxxxxxxx&language=ja&requesterCountryCode=JP